# android locationManager didn't callback onLocationChanged in LocationListener

Tags: android, locationmanager

I am developing an android app to track user's location. The problem is requestLocationUpdates() has been called but no response to LocationListener.

p.s. The GPS indicator is shown in the top status bar after requestLocationUpdates() called.

p.s. There is no such problem when using android 4.0 or before. After my Galaxy nexus is updated to 4.1, this problem occurred. Is this related to OS problem?

Anyone have idea one this? Many thanks!

the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

the locationManager:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

The locationListener:

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("onLocationChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("onProviderDisabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        System.out.println("onProviderEnabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        System.out.println("onStatusChanged");
    }
};
```

How it start:

```
Criteria c = new Criteria();
c.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);

final String PROVIDER = lm.getBestProvider(c, true);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(PROVIDER, 600000, 0, locationListener);
```